# How to read a file line by line, then print the line if it contains a string with a range of value in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm a newbie with Python 2.7 and I'm still trying to get the hang of it.

I have a text file with a row of lines that contain strings like this:

```
"AA,,BB,2014-02-06,0,0|CC,,DD,2014-02-27,0,0|EE,,FF,2014-02-04,1,1"#"GG"#"USD"#"true"#Total : USD#1638.93#
```

(There's a bunch of text before 'USD' that varies with each line.)

I tried doing this:

```
with open('out_put_usjfk50.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='#')
    for row in reader:
        amount = float(row[5])
        if amount <= 800:
            print row
        elif amount is None:
            pass
```

but I got the same error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

I'm stumped. How do I go through each line to check for the integer value (that's part of a string), and then print the line(s) if it's less than, say, USD1500? I'd appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction!

Comment: Does the text before USD contain numbers?

Comment: It does, but the numbers refer to dates. Eg: 2014-02-27

Comment: @jrd1 I've added the full line. Sorry about that!

Comment: Is that the whole line, switching delimiters like that?

Comment: Ah, the first column is quoted and is itself a comma-separated (nested) CSV-like line.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the whole line. :/ It's a weird output that I received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a CSV file; use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='#')
    for row in reader:
```

New each `row` object is a list of strings; each string representing a column in your file.

Say the `'1638.93'` column is column 8, then you'd use (with Python using 0-based indexing):

```
amount = float(row[7])
```

Now you have a floating point number from that string, and you can test against it:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='#')
    for row in reader:
        amount = float(row[7])
        if amount <= 1500:
            print row
```

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense! I never thought # could be a delimiter, and hence I didn't know it could function as a CSV file.

I've added the full line in my original question, and used `row[5]`, but for some reason, this error appeared: `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: @Infection: are you certain that *all* lines have a float value in column 6?

Comment: @Infection: Try printing out *just* `row[5]`, or use a `try:`, `except ValueError: print row[5]` exception handler around the `amount = ..` line to debug.

Comment: Ah you raised a good point. I just combed through the file again. Not _all_ lines have a float value actually. Occasionally it's empty, ie: `#"true"#Total : #`

Comment: @Infection: then it could be `amount = float(row[5]) if row[5] else 0`, or something similar.