# Read line in file, print line if it contains string

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I have a working code that opens a file, looks for a string, and prints the line if it contains that string. I'm doing this so that I can decide, manually, whether the line should be removed from my dataset or not.

But it would be much better if I can tell the program to read the part of the line that contains the string that is between two commas.

The code I have now (see below)

```
with open("dvd.txt") as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if " arnold " in line:
            num = str(num)
            print line + '' + num
```

Prints each line like this:

```
77.224998664,2014-10-19,386.5889,the best arnold ***** ,81,dvd-action,Cheese 5gr,online-dvd-king93,0.19976,18,/media/removable/backup/2014-10-19/all_items/cheese-5gr?feedback_page=1.html,    ships from: Germany    ships to: Worldwide  ,2014-07-30,online-dvd-king,93 1
```

I'd like it to print this instead:

```
,the best arnold ***** , 1
```

or

```
the best arnold *****  1
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616839/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-then-print-the-line-if-it-contains-a-string-wit) question, but I hope to avoid using CSV.

If it is for whatever reason tricky to find the text between commas, or any other specific characters, it'd be useful to print the 3 words before and after the string I'm looking for.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the CSV module to parse a CSV?

Comment: The files I need this for aren't always CSVs or similar spreadsheets

Comment: This is too broad, then. There are a ton of steps between, "is this word in this string" and "print only certain words from this string". Especially since you haven't actually shown us the format(s) you're working with.

Comment: the files are mostly in txt files, separated by lines

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is very simple to do with [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).  Modifying your function as follows will produce the output you want.

```
with open("dvd.csv") as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if " arnold " in line:
            num = str(num)
            print line.split(',')[3] + '' + num
```

`str.split` splits up a string into a list by the specified separator.  To access the list entry you want, simply supply the appropriate index (which in your case should be 3).

As an aside, you can produce your output with the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) method to make it a little nicer:

```
print "{} {}".format(line.split(',')[3], num)
```

This will also allow you to remove `num = str(num)` since the format method can handle multiple datatypes (as opposed to string concatenation which cannot).

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you could make use of a regular expression as follows:

```
with open("dvd.txt") as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        re_arnold = re.search(r',\s*([^,]*?arnold[^,]*?)\s*,', line)

        if re_arnold:
            print '{} {}'.format(re_arnold.group(1), num)
```

This would then extract the whole entry (between the commas) regardless of which field it is in.

Comment: If the search key varies in what entry it is (between which commas) this is definitely the better answer